# How to change permissions in files in subdirectories in linux?

Tags: linux

I have a main music folder and within that folder are the various albums that I have and in those albums are the various song files.

The permissions on these are set incorrectly on my FreeNAS server and I'm wondering how to change them to 0777 so I can change the tags on the songs.

Comment: Your last paragraph is broken. Also, does the `chmod -R` command not work for you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A simple mix of find and chmod will do the trick.

From an ssh window to your FreeNAS (or directly on console) and accepting that "/mnt/storage/music" is the real unix path of your "x:/music":

```
find /mnt/storage/music -type f -exec chmod 0777 {} \;
```

But in fact a 0666 would be enough, as simple files do not really need the "execution" permission bit ;)